# How to transform an UpperDiagonalMatrix into a symmetric matrix in Mathematica 5.2?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, map

I have an UpperDiagonalMatrix as the following, how to transform it into a symmetric matrix in Mathematica 5.2?  **Note:** don't use the command `c += Transpose[UpperTriangularize[c, 1]]`, because doesn't exist the the function `UpperTriangularize` in Mathematica 5.2. Thank you.

```
c = {{c11, c12, c13, c14}, {0, c22, c23, c24}, {0, 0, c33, c34}, {0, 
    0, 0, c44}};
```

[image]

the objective:

```
c = {{c11, c12, c13, c14}, {c12, c22, c23, c24}, {c13, c23, c33, 
   c34}, {c14, c24, c34, c44}}
```

[image]

Comment: Mathematica 5.2 was released 15 years ago.

Comment: @user6014, After the version 5.2, the **windows function** `UnitStep` was split to `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta`,  and sometimes the `UnitStep` gives birth to unexpected result in new version(for example Mathematica 11.3), so I always use the version 5.2 when involving the **windows function**.

Comment: `c + Transpose@c - c IdentityMatrix[4]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci, your answer is wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = {{c11, c12, c13, c14}, {0, c22, c23, c24}, {0, 0, c33, c34}, {0, 0, 0, c44}};

Table[c[[i, j]] = c[[j, i]], {i, 2, Length[c]}, {j, 1, i - 1}];

c // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

```
MapIndexed[c[[## & @@ Sort@#2]] &, c, {2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
c2 = Array[Function[, c[[##]], Orderless], Dimensions @ c]

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ c2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{c11} & \text{c12} & \text{c13} & \text{c14} \\
>  \text{c12} & \text{c22} & \text{c23} & \text{c24} \\
>  \text{c13} & \text{c23} & \text{c33} & \text{c34} \\
>  \text{c14} & \text{c24} & \text{c34} & \text{c44} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also,

```
SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
f[i_, j_] := c[[i, j]]

c3 = Array[f, Dimensions @ c]

c3 == c2
```

> True

and

```
c4 = Array[c[[##]] & @@ Sort[{##}] &, Dimensions[c]]

c4 == c2
```

> True

All functions used are available since version 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = c + Transpose[c];
Do[a[[i, i]] -= c[[i, i]], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem correctly, but, I can take only one solution as my answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @likehust You can vote Henrik's answer up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png).

Comment: @xzczd, I have clicked the upward gray triangles of yours and Henrik's, thanks.